# Is the if statement condition mutually-exclusive to multiple variables?

Tags: python, if-statement, multiple-conditions

Let's say that I have three lists and  want to add all elements that are integers to a list named `int_list`:

```
test1 = [1, 2, 3, "b", 6]
test2 = [1, "foo", "bar", 7]
test3 = ["more stuff", 1, 4, 99]
int_list = []
```

I know that I can do the following code to append all integers to a new list:

```
for elem1, elem2, elem3 in zip(test1, test2, test3):
    if elem1 is int:
        int_list.append(elem1)
    if elem2 is int:
        int_list.append(elem2)
    if elem3 is int:
        int_list.append(elem3)
```

Is there anyway that I can merge the if statements into one conditional statement? Or make it less code? Is there a more pythonic way to do this?
I tried doing the following code, but it would include elements that were not integers:

```
for elem1, elem2, elem3 in zip(test1, test2, test3):
        if (elem1 is int, elem2 is int, elem3 is int):
            int_list.append(elem1)
            int_list.append(elem2)
            int_list.append(elem3)
```

Comment: This will **not append** all integers per se, since `zip` will stop from the moment one of the lists has finished...

Comment: Furthermore `elem1 is int` **does not work**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some **problems** with your code:

1. `zip` constructs tuples of elements **as long as all lists have elements**, if one of the lists is exhausted, `zip` stops;
2. `elem1 is int` **does not do type-checking**, it does **reference equality checking**, you can use `isinstance(..)` for that; and
3. as [@Jean-FrançoisFabre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43005480/is-the-if-statement-condition-mutually-exclusive-to-multiple-variables/43005565?noredirect=1#comment73100676_43005565) says, the `if (...)` will **always succeed** since you test it with a tuple with one or more elements: regardless of the values of that tuple the *truthiness* is `True`.

Why not first **join them thogether**? You can for instance use a tuple of the lists, like:

```
for sublist in (test1,test2,test3):
    for x in sublist:
        if isinstance(x,int):
            int_list.append(x)
```

Or you can use list comprehension:

```
int_list = [x for sublist in (test1,test2,test3)
              for x in sublist if isinstance(x,int)]
```

Comment: There's no generator in your "use a generator" example.

Comment: @user2357112: yeah initially I wanted to use a generator to chain them together, but halfway I changed my mind.

Comment: also `(elem1 is int, elem2 is int, elem3 is int)` is always `True` because it's a non-empty tuple.

Answer (score 2):

You use `zip`, but you want [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain). Additionally [you should use `isinstance` to check class membership](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549854/3377150).

```
from itertools import chain

for elem in chain(test1, test2, test3):
    if isinstance(elem, int):
        int_list.append(elem)
```